# Change TextBox foreground color based on specific starting and closing tags

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox, wpf-controls

[image]I am developing WPF application in which I am using `TextBox` to write some text. I want to change foreground color of my textbox to red whenever user encloses particular text in textbox with `<qs>` (at start) and `<qe>` at end. Similarly text color should change to green if user encloses some text with `<as>` at start and `<ae>` at end. I searched a lot online but didn't find any information. Any help is highly appreciated.

Output is expected as depicted in image

Also, I am using MVVM in my application.

Comment: Have you tried writing a ValueConverter for this? Also: what are the exact rules that you want to use?

Comment: I have updated my question and  have placed an image which shows what is exactly expected.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF RichTextBox Syntax Highlighting Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17971300/wpf-richtextbox-syntax-highlighting-issue)

Comment: also, i am using MVVM in my application.

Answer (score 0):

As @Erno de Weerd commented you can use a custom ValueConvertert for this. Another way I can think of is to inherit `TextBox` and override `TextProperty` metadata to react to changes on that property. The following sample contains the two approaches:

The XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:wpfApp="clr-namespace:WpfApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <wpfApp:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <wpfApp:TextToColorConverter x:Key="TextToColorConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel >
        <TextBox Text="{Binding SomeString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 Foreground="{Binding SomeString, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource TextToColorConverter}}"
                 Margin="0,0,0,20"/>
        <wpfApp:MyCustomTextBox Text="{Binding SomeString, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindowViewModel only contains the bound property and implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _someString;

    public string SomeString
    {
        get => _someString;
        set
        {
            if (value == _someString) return;
            _someString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

First approach, IValueConverter:

```
public class TextToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var str = (string)value;
        if (str == null) return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        return str.StartsWith("<qs>") && str.EndsWith("<qe>") ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) :
            str.StartsWith("<as>") && str.EndsWith("<ae>") ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green) :
            new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the second one, we inherit from TextBox:

```
public class MyCustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    static MyCustomTextBox()
    {
        TextProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyCustomTextBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(OnTextChanged));
    }

    private static void OnTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (MyCustomTextBox)d;
        var str = (string)e.NewValue;
        SolidColorBrush foreGround;
        if (str == null)
        {
            foreGround = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        }
        else
        {
            foreGround = str.StartsWith("<qs>") && str.EndsWith("<qe>") ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) :
                str.StartsWith("<as>") && str.EndsWith("<ae>") ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green) :
                new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        }

        control.Foreground = foreGround;
    }
}
```

I personally prefer the second approach, creating my own custom control allows me to use that control in as many views as I want without needing to include always an instance of a converter in my XAML, furthermore, if you were going to need some more custom behavior then you just add that behavior to your custom control instead of writing many many other converters.

Comment: Thanks, but it partially works. It only works if complete text is enclosed within (<qs> , <qe>) or (<as> , <ae>)  tags. It doesn't change text color if single word or multiple words are enclosed by tags within large sentence.

Comment: Then you need a RichTextBox as @Greg commented

Comment: Can you please share an example.

Comment: I am stuck, Someone Please help.